# Produce json message with headers via kafka CLI

Tags: shell, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Try to produce simple message via `kafka kafka-console-producer.sh`

Message:

```
{"status": "success", "properties": []}
```

Headers:

```
HeaderKey1:HeaderValue1
HeaderKey2:HeaderValue2
```

It’s not clear from the CLI API how this can be done

Source message.txt file:

```
HeaderKey1:HeaderValue1
HeaderKey2:HeaderValue2

{"status": "success", "properties": []}
```

```bash
cat message.txt | \
  docker exec -i kafka kafka-console-producer.sh \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --topic test_topic \
  --property parse.key=true \
  --property key.separator=\n \
  --property headers.delimiter=:
```

Expect that the headers will go into the headers, and the json will go into the value

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `--property parse.headers=true` since the default is [false](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleProducer.scala#L276). Also I think you need to rewrite your message like this:

```
h1:v1,h2:v2;{"status": "success", "properties": []}
```

And produce with this:

```
--property parse.headers=true  --property headers.delimiter=';'
```

This will work since the defaults are: `headers.key.separator=:` and `headers.separator=,`

```
Headers:
            Key: h1   Value: v1
            Key: h2   Value: v2
Partition:   2
Offset:      20
Timestamp:   2024-03-05 21:04:07.134 +0000 GMT
{
 "properties": [],
 "status": "success"
}
```